# Remove/Delete textbox based on dropbox selection

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have this code below containing a dropdown list and two textboxes with ids "OtherName" and "OtherDesc". I want to remove/delete the two textboxes when any value other than "other" is selected from the dropdown list. Here is my code but it isnt working any idea why?

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


            <div id="OtherName" class="form-group" >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tbl_Category.CategoryName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tbl_Category.CategoryName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                </div>
            </div>

        <div id="OtherDesc" class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tbl_Category.CategoryDesc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tbl_Category.CategoryDesc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //this line fires no matter what
        $("#OtherName").hide();
        $("#OtherDesc").hide();

        $("#CategoryId").change(function () {
            var value = document.getElementById("CategoryId").value;
            if (value == "1011") {
                $("#OtherName").show();
                $("#OtherDesc").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#OtherName").remove();
                $("#OtherDesc").remove();
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Some advice how to change your code:

1. You can combine your element selector.
2. Use `hide` instead of `remove`. Otherwise your elements are gone forever.
3. You already uses jQuery, so thy not get the value over jQuery too?
4. Because you only need the value once, there is no need for a variable declaration `value`.
5. There is a shorthand `$(function() {});` for `$(document).ready(function() {});`.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = $("#OtherName, #OtherDesc").hide();

    $("#CategoryId").change(function() {
        if( $(this).val() == "1011" )
            boxes.show();
        else
            boxes.hide();
    });
});
```

Even shorter you can go with `toggle` instead of `show` and `hide`:

```
$(function() {
    var boxes = $("#OtherName, #OtherDesc").hide();

    $("#CategoryId").change(function() {
        boxes.toggle($(this).val() == "1011");
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to remove coz I am having an error otherwise. Is there a way to remove?

Comment: If you remove them, you can't bring them back easily. They are deleted from the document. What errors do you got? Maybe when can solve them.

Comment: The fields of the hidden textboxes are assigned to null and thus the thing I am creating is not created it's not validating. But if I dont put them it works fine and if I choose other it also works fine, therefore I thought of removing.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I don't know your validation. Maybe removing/disabling the validation of the fields? Or create an own validation for the fields?

Comment: I am only setting the categoryname and category description ie the two textboxes that I am hiding currently to Required that's all

Comment: Can I set them to a value other than null using jquery?

Comment: Sure. In my example you can do it like this: `boxes.val("vour value");`

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` removes the element from dom completely.You need to use `.hide()` instead of removing the elements.

also you can optimize your code in many ways. Like

1)use clicked context of select rather than getting it by id again

2)Use multiple selectors to target both element and then show/hide them with one call.

```
$("#CategoryId").change(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        $("#OtherName,#OtherDesc").toggle(value == "1011");
});
```

Comment: In your case, you miss the initial hiding and has to select the elements then two times, inside and outside of your event handler. Or you trigger the `change` event one time manually.

Comment: @eisbehr: i only modified select handler. there is no issue in other code :)